# Find the image of a triangle under the mapping $w=1/z$

Tags: complex-numbers

The triangle is $\{z=x+iy: x \geq 0, y \geq 0, x+y\leq1\}$. Could anyone help me with this? I also wonder how to solve this kind of problem in general.

Specifically, I want to how the hypotenuse gets mapped.

Comment: how do you invert a complex number? hint: $\bar z z = |z|^2$.

Comment: Where do the vertices go? This much is easy. The edges, perhaps you can paramterize the legs of the triangle as paths, and invert those?

Comment: There is an issue with (0,0) though, That should be taken out of the given domain. Otherwise, Alfred's suggestion is nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is essentially what's called a Mobius transformation.
More information can be found in this link:
http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~cwalkden/hyperbolic-geometry/lecture03.pdf

Now the essential part is that under such a transformation:

1) Lines through O become lines through O (with O a perforation)
2) Lines not through O become circles through O (with O a perforation)
3) Circles through O become lines not through O (with O a perforation)
4) Circles not through O become circles not through O

Your region is a triangle consisting of three lines, two of them through O. With this information you can determine the images by selecting "easy" points on the given boundaries and invert point by point. The line $x+y=1$ becomes a circle so if you have three image points of that line, an equation of the circle can be easy obtained.

Answer (score 0):

$w=\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{x+iy}=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}+i\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}$
Let $u=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ and $v=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}$ then $u^2+v^2=1$. Since $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$ then $u\ge 0$ and $v \le 0$.

Now, at the point $(x,y)=(1,0)$ we are at $(u,v)=(1,0)$ and at $(x,y)=(0,1)$ we are at $(u,v)=(0,-1)$, so we are out side the line that joins (1,0) and (0,-1) in the fourth quadrant i.e., $
\left\{ {\left( {u,v} \right):v  = u-1, u \ge 0,v \le 0} \right\}
$.

Comment: Point (1/2 , 1/2) is mapped onto (1,-1) so the circle cannot be the unit circle

Comment: Yes, you are right ... i edit

Comment: $u^2+v^2$ is not equal to $1$